# Additional wrong event being triggered when using bootstrap collpase button

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.2 and I have two buttons that can hide content, using the Bootstrap collapse plugin.

```
       <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto">
            <span class="pe-2">
                <button id="show_movements_button" type="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#movements_id">
                    Show Movements
                </button>
            </span>
            <span class="pe-2">
                <button id="show_credits_button" type="btn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#credits_id">
                    Show All Credits
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

such as

```
<tr class="song_id collapse" id="movements_id">
    <td class="col-1">
        1
    </td>
    <td class="col">
    </td>
    <td class="col">
        <div>
            <label class="h6">
                Piano Concerto no. 1 in E minor, op. 11: I. Allegro maestoso
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="credits_id">
            <div class="lh-1">
                <div>
                    <a href="/container.start?cid=0$=Instrument$708&amp;title=Instruments+%2F+piano" class="small text-secondary">
                        piano
                    </a>
                    <label class="small">
                         by 
                    </label>
                    <a href="/container.start?cid=0$=Performer_name$5540&amp;title=Performers+%2F+Evgeny+Kissin" class="small text-secondary pe-1">
                        Evgeny Kissin
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This work correctly, but I want the name of the button to change to indicate if showing or hiding content so I also have this code

```
<script>

function listenForButtonCollapse(buttonId, collapseId, buttonShowText, buttonHideText)
{
    let button  = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    let section = document.getElementById(collapseId);
    if(section!=null)
    {
        section.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse',
            function()
            {
                button.innerText=buttonHideText;
            }
        );

        section.addEventListener('hide.bs.collapse',
            function()
            {
                button.innerText=buttonShowText;
            }
        );
    }
}
  </script>
  <script>
       listenForButtonCollapse('show_credits_button','credits_id','Show All Credits','Hide Some Credits');
  </script>
  <script>
      listenForButtonCollapse('show_movements_button','movements_id','Show Movements','Hide Movements');
  </script>
```

Now toggling the *Show/Hide Movements* button works fine, but when I click on the *Show/Hide Credits* button for some reason it is also triggering the *listenForButtonCollapse()* call on the movements button as well as the credits button, so the Movement button is updated with the same (Hide/Show) value as the credits button even though it isn't actually been invoked (so it doesn't hide/show the movements div)

The credits div is within the movements div, so Im assuming that why one button works without problem and the other doesn't but I cant see what I am actually doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the current behaviour you need to stop further event propagation. You can do this by using [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). This method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```js
function listenForButtonCollapse(buttonId, collapseId, buttonShowText, buttonHideText)
{
    let button  = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    let section = document.getElementById(collapseId);
    
    if (section != null)
    {
        section.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse',
            function(event)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                button.innerText=buttonHideText;
            }
        );

        section.addEventListener('hide.bs.collapse',
            function(event)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                button.innerText=buttonShowText;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I've prepared a Code playground to illustrate that this solves your issue:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/bootstrap-5-playground-forked-b28j0g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**Solution Explanation**

The events `show.bs.collapse` and `hide.bs.collapse` are being triggered for both buttons when clicked. So when you add more than one event listener for those events, when the event occurs, all event listeners are being executed. This is why for example when you click *"Hide Movements"* and bootstrap triggers `hide.bs.collapse`
event then this executes all registered event listeners for it - in this case two - one for the `show_credits_button` and another for `show_movements_button`  button - leading to changing both button texts. To prevent this you need to stop further event propagation with `event.stopPropagation()` method - this will stop notifying all other event listeners for this event other than the event target one.

Comment: Thankyou, I have implemented your suggestion and it works perfectly, but I don't quite understand the cause of the issue, why does it propogate to another button ? Could you add an explanation to your answer please.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I've updated my answer with **Solution Explanation** section, hope it clarifies the solution.

Comment: thanks, so when click on a button both listeners recieve event, so how do we ensure the correct listener recieves the evetn not the incorrect one ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor it is related to the event target. The `stopPropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and phases. When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it.